# Get all user (+ direct manager, photo meta data and properties like 'AboutMe')

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Until now we used a SharePoint on-premise custom web service which delivered all users (approx 15,000) inclusive properties like `aboutMe`, `skills`, etc. and the direct manager. That job took approx. 15 minutes.
All the data was stored in a Lucene search index.

Now we have to switch to O365.
I am able to get all the desired information from Microsoft Graph but it would take way too long (3 - 5 hours):

- Fetch all users via `/v1.0/users` (with paging)
- Iterate through the collection and

  - get manager for given user via `/v1.0/[user-id]/manager`
  - get properties like `aboutMe`, `skills` for given User via `/v1.0/[user-Id]?$select=aboutMe,skills`

Is there any efficient way to do that task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should just call Microsoft Graph for the data you want on-demand rather than attempting to sync it to your own database.

Assuming you can't do that, you can deduce the time this takes using `/delta` endpoint ([Get incremental changes for users](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_users)). When you use a delta token, you will only get back resources that have changed (adds, deletes, edits) since your previous request. So your first pass might take a few hours, but subsequent passes should take seconds.

You can control which properties you're "tracking changes" against using the `$select` query parameter. For example, if you only care about changes to the `displayName` then using `/v1.0/users/delta?$select=displayName` will ensure you only receive changes to that property. From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_overview#optional-query-parameters):

> If a `$select` query parameter is used, the parameter indicates that the client prefers to only track changes on the properties or relationships specified in the `$select` statement. If a change occurs to a property that is not selected, the resource for which that property changed does not appear in the delta response after a subsequent request.

Also, consider [batching requests](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching) to improve your processes' overall performance. Batching allows you to send multiple queries to Microsoft Graph in a single request and get the complete results back in a single response.

Comment: Hmm... but it only recognizes changes on user properties selected by query (/users/?query=[props]) or the default properties (without query GET param)?
Is there any chance to recognize if there was an update on a user (like profile image, direct manager, special properties like aboutMe, skills)?

Comment: Yes, you can control which properties are returned/tracked in the delta. I've updated my answer with this information.

Comment: So all properties - which are available for /users endpoint - are trackable. Other user properties like 'manager', 'photo', 'aboutMe' - which are only available via /user endpoint - are not trackable. Is there any way to get all added/changed/deleted users, where the delta is determined through a global state (like e.g. 'updatetimestamp')? Maybe with another API, Azure Graph API? Thanks for your help btw :)